# Why does this code changes location as I need it to

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a weird question. I have been writing a code to change the view by a `<select>`'s `onchange` like this:

```
<% Html.BeginForm(); %>
<label for="id" >Automat:</label>
<%= Html.DropDownList("id", Model as SelectList, new { @onchange = "window.location.href = document.getElementById('id').options[document.getElementById('id').selectedIndex].value;" })%>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

The selected value is numeric (i.e. 1,2,...).

Suddenly, I am able by changing the selected option to go from URL

```
http://localhost:58296/Content/ViewContent/2
```

to

```
http://localhost:58296/Content/ViewContent/3
```

.. And I really don't know why it works. Can anyone explain that to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected index of the drop down list is a 0-based index of the items in the list.

```
<select>
  <option>Some Option 1</option> <!-- I have index 0 -->
  <option>Some Option 2</option> <!-- I have index 1 -->
  <option>Some Option 3</option> <!-- I have index 2 -->
</select>
```

You are literally telling the select list, "When you change, grab the selected index of the value, and change the very last part of the URL to that index."

Comment: Ok, already helpful, but where do I say change only the last part of the URL? I thought changing the window.location.href property should change the whole URL.

Comment: @Trimack it follows the same logic as `a href`. Unless you have a leading `http(s)://`, it will be treated as a relative location.